# Furu meaning in sentences

Tags: meaning, words

Kaze ga furu and Ame ga furu. The wind is blowing and the rain is falling. Are the two sentences written correctly? TYVM.

Comment: "Assume"? Is there any particular reason you didn't even use a dictionary?

Comment: @naruto, I used a dictionary, but it seems that furu is more of a doing meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you mistook *fuku* for *furu* about the wind?

Usually, it is *fuku* (吹く) for wind and *furu* (降る) for rain.